# How can I get GIT/SSH to look for "known_hosts" in a specific location?

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I am using GIT as part of an automated build process on Ubuntu Linux. Because it's an automated build process, it is preferrable to have all configuration in version control, so that I don't have to log in to each build agent when the configuration changes.

To get this to work, I have a private key (with read-only repo access) and a known_hosts file checked in to version control.

I set the HOME environment variable to a location within my version control (build/ssh_home) in order to allow GIT to locate my known_hosts file (build/ssh_home/.ssh/known_hosts).

I use the following command to "activate" the private key and pull from GIT. The "git clone" step is similar.

```
ssh-agent bash -c "echo $HOME; ssh-add '${deploymentKey}' >/dev/null 2>&1; git pull ${repository} --quiet"
```

This works on Windows. However, on Ubuntu Linux, this is not sufficient.

The "HOME" environment variable is set as follows (in a bash script)

```
export HOME=`pwd`/build/ssh_home
```

However, it's clearly not using the right known_hosts file, it's still trying to use the one in ~/.ssh/known_hosts, evidenced by the path cited in the message below.

```
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (131.103.20.168)' can't be established. 
RSA key fingerprint is 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40. 
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes 
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts).
```

**How can I get GIT (SSH) to use a known_hosts file in a specific location (not in my home directory)?**

**EDIT:**

Permissions on my "build/ssh_home" directory (requested in comments)

```
ls -la build/ssh_home
total 16
drwx------  3 ben ben 4096 Jun 18 10:52 .
drwxrwxr-x 39 ben ben 4096 Jun 18 10:52 ..
-rw-------  1 ben ben  209 Jun 18 10:52 readme.txt
drwx------  2 ben ben 4096 Jun 18 10:52 .ssh
```

Permissions on build/ssh_home/.ssh

```
ls -la build/ssh_home/.ssh
total 12
drwx------ 2 ben ben 4096 Jun 18 10:52 .
drwx------ 3 ben ben 4096 Jun 18 10:52 ..
-rw------- 1 ben ben 2402 Jun 18 10:52 known_hosts
```

Permissions on my "~/.ssh" directory (requested in comments)

```
myusername@myhostname:~$ ls -la ~/.ssh
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun 29 10:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 ben  ben  4096 May 21 15:39 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  427 May 19 11:27 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 root root 1679 May 19 11:27 bitbucket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  398 May 19 11:27 bitbucket.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   63 May 19 11:27 config
```

Comment: @Makoto I'll add that one too. However, my key issue is that I don't want to have to mess with `~/.ssh/known_hosts` on the build system. I want to maintain all configuration within version control.

Comment: So essentially no one answers your question, which is - "how to make git recognize a custom known_hosts file path". Rather folks answer a different question - how to make ssh recognize a custom known_hosts file. Not the same at all. I actually need to implement exactly your scenario. Have you found the way? Could you provide your own answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the location of the `known_hosts` file by:

`ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/path/to/known_hosts`

For example, if you want to test SSH connection to GitHub, you could do:

`ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/path/to/known_hosts -T git@github.com`

This will add github.com (IP ADDRESS) to the `known_hosts` file and you would then see a message like:

```
Hi <github_username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

You can then do `cat /path/to/known_hosts` to check the contents.

Mine looks like:

```
github.com,192.30.255.112 ssh-rsa ...
...
...==
192.30.255.113 ssh-rsa ...
...
...==
```

Answer (score 0):

`root` owns the directory, not you.  You've got to change that:

```
sudo chown -R ben:ben ~/.ssh
```

Then you're going to want to change the permissions in that directory.  The directory overall should be 0600.

```
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh
```

I actively discourage adding the known_hosts file to source control, since that's really not something that should be made "public" - and [there are ways](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26282/13623) to circumvent the issue of not auto-accepting a new key to the system.

Comment: You are right, ownership of '~/.ssh' was causing the issue "Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts)". But it doesn't make SSH use my known_hosts file in a custom location.
You are right, the info in known_hosts is not really "public" info, but at the same time, it only contains public keys, so it is not sensitive. I would argue that it is *more secure* to have known_hosts in VCS than to disable strict host key checking. However in the absence of a working solution I will likely end up using the solution you linked, thank you!